# Prevent DHCP queries for a particular interface

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi, dhcp

I have a laptop with a Wi-Fi card and an Ethernet card, both connected to the same network.  Despite my best efforts to disable the Wi-Fi, my system keeps trying to obtain an address for it, not only that, it generates a new hardware address every time it does so.  This clogs the switch'es routing tables...

Here's what I tried to do:

In `/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service`

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd -q -b -Z wlp3s0
```

(the `wlp3s0` is the name of the Wi-Fi interface).  But, I still see in the `dhcpcd` log:

```
...
Jan 15 10:50:20 [redacted] dhcpcd[2012]: wlp3s0: new hardware address: ae:a5:10:83:e5:58
Jan 15 10:55:36 [redacted] dhcpcd[2012]: wlp3s0: new hardware address: 46:9d:71:de:0b:34
Jan 15 11:00:52 [redacted] dhcpcd[2012]: wlp3s0: new hardware address: a6:4f:44:19:41:a1
```

The interface appears in some bizarre state (after me trying to disable it):

```
ip address show wlp3s0
2: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:c6:bc:00:82:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I don't understand how can it be both `UP` and `DOWN` at the same time...

So... I don't care in what way can I disable the further DHCP queries for this interface, beside physically pulling out the Wi-Fi card (this is the company's laptop, I cannot pull it apart).  Anything outside that that will prevent the queries will help.

The OS is Arch, I'm using `netctl` for the networking, and I've checked the active profiles: none of them use the Wi-Fi interface.

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do this. Here is two:

1. Blacklist the module corresponding to the driver of your Wifi card. (see [this doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module). Usually it is done by creating a file on /etc/modprobe.d which content is "blacklist ")
2. Edit `dhcpcd` configuration file to deny your Wifi NIC (see [man 5 dhcpcd.conf](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/dhcpcd.conf.5))